# markdown not working for additional spaces?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, markdown

In a attempt to convert `md` to `html` file I am using this regex to replace all matching code's ending with `\n` to `\n\t`. The problem is its matching when using `search()` but not when using `sub()`. Need help.

````
import markdown2
import re

code_text = """* But why did the `is` operator evaluated to `False`? Let's see with this snippet.
  ```py
  class WTF(object):
    def __init__(self): print("I ")
    def __del__(self): print("D ")
  ```

  **Output:**"""

print("PROBLEM :: \n", markdown2.markdown(code_text))

pattern = re.compile(r"```py(?P<code>.*?)```", re.DOTALL)

code_only = pattern.search(code_text).group("code")

code_only = code_only.replace("\n", "\n\t")

print("SOLUTION 1:: \n", markdown2.markdown(code_only))

###################################################
# Replacing all code occurrences in the given string

code_only = pattern.sub(lambda m: (m.group("code")).replace("\n", "\n\t"), code_text)

print("SOLUTION 2:: \n", markdown2.markdown(code_only))
````

**OUTPUT :**

```
PROBLEM :: 
 <ul>
<li><p>But why did the <code>is</code> operator evaluated to <code>False</code>? Let's see with this snippet.
<code>py
class WTF(object):
def __init__(self): print("I ")
def __del__(self): print("D ")
</code></p>

<p><strong>Output:</strong></p></li>
</ul>

SOLUTION 1:: 
 <pre><code>  class WTF(object):
    def __init__(self): print("I ")
    def __del__(self): print("D ")
</code></pre>

SOLUTION 2:: 
 <ul>
<li><p>But why did the <code>is</code> operator evaluated to <code>False</code>? Let's see with this snippet.</p>

<p>class WTF(object):
    def <strong>init</strong>(self): print("I ")
    def <strong>del</strong>(self): print("D ")</p>

<p><strong>Output:</strong></p></li>
</ul>
```

Try changing `code_text` to

````
```py
>>> a = "some_string"
>>> id(a)
140420665652016
>>> id("some" + "_" + "string") # Notice that both the ids are same.
140420665652016
```
### This is a heading
```py
print("Hello World")
```
````

it works perfectly.

**OUTPUT :**

````
PROBLEM :: 

 <p>```py</p>

<blockquote>
  <blockquote>
    <blockquote>
      <p>a = "some<em>string"
      id(a)
      140420665652016
      id("some" + "</em>" + "string") # Notice that both the ids are same.
      140420665652016
      ```</p>

      <h3>This is a heading</h3>
    </blockquote>
  </blockquote>
</blockquote>

<p><code>py
print("Hello World")
</code></p>

SOLUTION 1:: 
 <pre><code>&gt;&gt;&gt; a = "some_string"
&gt;&gt;&gt; id(a)
140420665652016
&gt;&gt;&gt; id("some" + "_" + "string") # Notice that both the ids are same.
140420665652016
</code></pre>

SOLUTION 2:: 
 <pre><code>&gt;&gt;&gt; a = "some_string"
&gt;&gt;&gt; id(a)
140420665652016
&gt;&gt;&gt; id("some" + "_" + "string") # Notice that both the ids are same.
140420665652016
</code></pre>

<h3>This is a heading</h3>

<pre><code>print("Hello World")
</code></pre>
````

**EDIT 1**

Tried using Pypi markdown

**OUTPUT :**

```
PROBLEM :: 
 <ul>
<li><p>But why did the <code>is</code> operator evaluated to <code>False</code>? Let's see with this snippet.
<code>py
class WTF(object):
def __init__(self): print("I ")
def __del__(self): print("D ")
</code></p>

<p><strong>Output:</strong></p></li>
</ul>

SOLUTION 1:: 
 <pre><code>  class WTF(object):
    def __init__(self): print("I ")
    def __del__(self): print("D ")
</code></pre>

SOLUTION 2:: 
 <ul>
<li>
<p>But why did the <code>is</code> operator evaluated to <code>False</code>? Let's see with this snippet.</p>
<p>class WTF(object):
    def <strong>init</strong>(self): print("I ")
    def <strong>del</strong>(self): print("D ")</p>
</li>
</ul>
<p><strong>Output:</strong></p>
```

**EDIT 2 :**

The `sub()` works fine. I just confirmed it, but since the code already had `\n\t` at the end of each line so after running it it became `\n\t\t` and now the `markdown()` doesn't work.

Comment: You might use [PyPi Markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/#features) for that (*Python-Markdown can output documents with either HTML or XHTML style tags*).

Comment: Tried, didn't work.

Comment: The `sub()` works. Sorry about that. mardown is not working if there are additional spaces.